# How to create and connect functions to vpython button?

Tags: python, spring, function, button, vpython

I am going to create a GUI interface  to calculate time period by taking mass(m) and stiffness(k) as input values from a user. I have tried to create the interface in glowscript but at the time to bind function to calculate button, errors are created saying: `t is not defined`. I am not getting what to do further to calculate time period and print on the screen. Please help me solve this problem.

```
scene.width = 750
scene.height = 530
scene.range = 1.1
#scene.title = "SpringMass System\n\n"
scene.background = vector(0.9,0.9,0.9)
scene.align = "right"

    
scene.caption = "<b>Effect of Stiffness on Time Period  </b>\n\n\n"
#button(text="Pause", pos=scene.title_anchor,color=color.white,background=vec(0,0,0.6), bind=Run)
Mass=box(pos=vector(0,-1,0),velocity=vector(0,0,0),size=vector(1.27,1,1.2),color=vec(0,0,0.4),mass=1.0)
pivot=vector(0,4,0)
spring=helix(pos=pivot, axis=Mass.pos-pivot, radius=0.4, constant=1, thickness=0.1, coils=15, color=color.red)
wall=box(pos=pivot,size=vector(3,0.2,3),color=color.green)
```

## Below is the part where I am getting error

```
   # mass input
def m(x):
 print (x.number)
m=winput(bind=m,width=130, prompt=" Enter mass(m):       ",type="numeric")
wtext(text=" kg")
scene.append_to_caption('\n\n\n')

#Stiffness input
def k(y):
 print (y.number)
k=winput(bind=k,width=130,prompt=" Enter Stiffness(k):   ",type="numeric")
wtext(text=" N/m")
scene.append_to_caption('\n\n')


#Calculate TimePeriod   
def calculate(t):
 T=2*3.14/(sqrt(y/x))
 return T
scene.append_to_caption('\nTime Period = '+t.number+'\n')  


button(bind=calculate ,text ="<b>  Calculate  </b>",color=color.white,background=color.blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function "calculate(t)" doesn't do anything with the local variable t, nor has this function been called at the time that you execute scene.append_to_caption('\nTime Period = '+t.number+'\n'), so indeed t has not been defined when you execute this statement.

We encourage people to post to the VPython or GlowScript user forum rather than to Stackoverflow, as there is a larger number of knowledgeable users in the VPython forum and you'll get faster response.